# Ionic Pull to refresh- New json data is not holding the latest data

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

Hi I am making a news website app using Ionic. The website is running on wordpress and the json api plugin I am using is called "JSON API". I am getting latest news by json call using http service from my app. Here is the link what I am calling.

```
http://example.com/api/get_category_posts/slug=sportscount=10&status=publish&page=1
```

Everything is working fine except pull to refresh. When I do the pull to refresh the corresponding function is working and json data is loading. But the new json data is not the latest data(I checked it in the network bar in chrome developer tool).
Everytime I do the pull to refresh the same previous json data is loading again and again. But when I restart the application then I get the latest json data.
I am not sure why it's not working? Let me clarify my problem again, every time http.get is called and return the json object when I do pull to refresh but the new json object is not holding the latest data?
Does Ionic cache the json object?
Should I have to programmatically refresh the json call from my service? If yes then how to do this?

I don't think any sample code is required in this question, so I didn't put my code here.

Comment: sample code is required since the error is probably in the code?

Comment: Hi, @AaronSaunders Finally I found the problem testing the same code with another wordpress site. My code is working fine with the new wordpress site. I think my client's website forcefully caching the data into the respective device(In browser and mobile devices). When I disable cache from my chrome network tab then it works. I also set

{cache: false}
But it not works.
My browser don't take any cache for my test website what is working fine.
Then I talked with my client and he said he is using cloudflare CDN for his website. Now I am thinking how can solve the problem?

Comment: @AliHayder: If you use cloudflare then in the cloudflare admin under *Cache* click *Purge everything*. But the proper way to solve it, so that you won't need to purge any cdn or browser cache is to set new timestamped URLs with every new build, so that the URLs look like e.g. `https://host.com/somepath.json?v=12345678590`